# How to specify user defined na.actions in dummyVars from caret package in R?

Tags: r, r-caret, dummy-variable

I am creating a dummyVars model and do a prediction for the different data. If some column of this data contained NA, the NAs are also transformed to a sparse matrix. Let me give an example.

Suppose this is my training:

```
customers <- data.frame(
             id=c(10,20,30,40,50),
             gender=c('male','female','female','male','female'),
             mood=c('happy','sad','happy','sad','happy'),
             outcome=c(1,1,0,0,0))

dmy <- dummyVars("~.", data = customers)
```

Now here is my data I want to transform to dummy variables:

```
customersTest <- data.frame(
                 id=c(1),
                 gender=c('female'),
                 mood=as.factor(c(NA)),
                 outcome=c(1),
                 Stuff = c("bla"))
```

If I predict for this data, I get an NA in all dummy mood states:

```
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = customersTest))

  > id gender.female gender.male mood.happy mood.sad outcome
  > 1             1           0         NA       NA       1
```

I want these NAs to be also 0, as neither happy nor sad mood is present in my data. As dummyVars predict has an `na.action` option, I was trying to write some customised function `f` inside which replaces all NAs with zeroes. This, however, didn't work.

Is there any way to do it via `na.action`? The option to replace all NAs with zeroes in the resulting data frame is already used by me and is quite RAM consuming for larger data sets. I would love to get rid of that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
DF1 = data.frame(C1= c(1, 5, 14, NA, 54), C2= c(9, NA, NA, 3, 42), C3= c(9, 7, 42, 87, NA))
DF1
#>   C1 C2 C3
#> 1  1  9  9
#> 2  5 NA  7
#> 3 14 NA 42
#> 4 NA  3 87
#> 5 54 42 NA

DF1[is.na(DF1)] = 0
DF1
#>   C1 C2 C3
#> 1  1  9  9
#> 2  5  0  7
#> 3 14  0 42
#> 4  0  3 87
#> 5 54 42  0
```